# Python - For loop not outputting in VSC

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

Why does a for loop not print values in the terminal? Is this a setting issue or something bigger? I've tried to look it up but just have had no luck.

Example:

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i)
```

Comment: It works fine here, what error you're facing?

Comment: >>> for i in range(1,10):
...     print(i)
...

This is what I get. I'm not sure if this is a setting or somethign but I would like it to print out each value if possible

Comment: ... in interactive means that the interpreter need more input. In this case (a block) you need an empty line before it can recognize it

Comment: LMAO. Sorry, I'm new to vsc/programming. I'm dumb. Thanks a lot! haha